# Does Android always call back listeners in the same order they have been registered?

Tags: android, listener

In my application I register several listeners to Preference changes via the registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912553/how-do-threads-interact-with-listeners-in-android) gave me a hint (listeners called in a single thread, sequential calling), and it seems rather obvious, but I could not find any confirmation of the calling order and my algorithm is dependent on the order.

Anyone can confirm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calling order is undocumented, and therefore you should not rely upon it.

Comment: Hmmm, this is what I feared. Well said, I just have to change my code then!